# Hardware to Detect EMG or Skin Resistance

Tags: pic, embedded, resistance, biopotential, skin-effect

I have been given assignment to design a device that can detect emg signal of Skin Resistance change while moving 
fingers.

actually **i need to track finger movements using some hardware containing micro controller**

My idea was that i will apply voltage at two points one finger tip and one elbow.

and measure voltage change by amplifying it.

Today i tested this idea by applying 1 volt and measuring by Ossiloscope .I donot know why there was 50 Hz AC wave detected there and there was very very slight change.

but i am not much happy with the results.

any idea?may be something mile a glove that sends computer a signal through some PIC/AVR or what ever
Any Idea or help is required.Consider what would you do in this case keeping in mind safety?

Comment: The phrase "emg signal of Skin Resistance change" makes no sense.  EMG is a measure of the voltage produced by contracting muscles.  Skin resistance is totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in Europe? The 50Hz seems to be coming from the power lines and if that noise is really bothering you, you should design some sort of notch filter to remove it. Depending on how far you go, you could maybe even use an adaptive filter that will cancel out that noise without losing any data you might need (frequencies around 50Hz) but that seems unnecessary for your assignment.

In order to get reasonable voltage levels, you need to amplify your signals tremendously. I can't remember the exact value off the top of my head, but EMG signals are relatively strong. You may be able to get away with a gain of less than 1000 in order to get peak-to-peak values of about 5V. The explanation of the amplifier will come later.

There are two types of electrodes that I am aware of that you can use to measure EMG signals: unipolar and bipolar. Your electrodes are probably unipolar and so I will assume this for the rest of the post.

You cannot just have two electrodes to measure EMG. You MUST have a reference point (i.e. your ground point). This, I would put at the elbow, or somewhere bony that will pick up very little electrical activity. Once you have a reference point, only then can you select two points on the body and then measure the difference in voltage levels between the two. In short, you must have at least three electrodes (if using unipolar electrodes).

You are going to have to use a differential amplifier (or instrumentation amplifier for better gain) in order to achieve this because you need to find the voltage difference between two points of the body. So you would tie your reference point (elbow) to virtual ground, and then tie the other two electrode outputs into the inputs of an instrumentation amplifier. You can look it up on wikipedia if you want to design your own, but it is probably easiest to buy an instrumentation amplifier. The INA128 (I think, from TI) should work fine.

You should double check the typical frequency range of EMG signals, but they are high compared to other biosignals that are typically measured. This being said, you should pass your amplified signal through some sort of bandpass filter for better results and higher immunity to noise. Another method, which might be better, is to integrate the signal (periodic muscle contractions should look almost like a square wave). This way, when you are interfacing with a PIC/AVR microcontroller, you can check voltage levels (which will correspond to intensity of muscle contraction) through the ADC channels.

Long answer, probably got worse as the answer went on but I hope this can be of use to you.

Comment: Notch filter isn't the right way to deal with it.  Prevent it from getting into your signal in the first place instead of filtering it out afterwards.  EEG devices use the "driven right leg amplifier", for instance, to cancel out most of the common-mode noise caused by the power lines, and then differential amplifiers to cancel out what's left.

Comment: can you tell any number and what do you mean by right leg amp

Answer (score 4):

That technique won't work - there is no relationship between skin resistance and finger position when measured between the finger tip and the elbow. You aren't measuring it correctly, anyway. You need silver/silver chloride electrodes with electrode jelly, high-gain amplifiers, and a lot of filtering and screening. Abrading the skin with electrode jelly and paper towel helps.

EMG won't work, either.

The DataGloves we used when I worked on advanced cockpit research at BAe used fibre optics. Strain on the optic fibre (it had a small cut in it) running along each finger over the knuckles reduced the intensity of the transmitted light. Detecting and amplifying the change gave the degree of flexure of each finger. A 3D electro-magnetic sensor attached to the back of the hand in conjunction with a magnetic field generator gave us the position of the hand and how it was moving (X, Y, Z, and roll, pitch and yaw).